# Select records only if all matching records are same value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

| id | food | type | nutrition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | chicken | meat | healthy |
| 2 | salad | vegetable | healthy |
| 3 | burger | meat | unhealthy |

I want to query all types of food which are completely healthy. The expected result here is only vegetable because burger is considered unhealthy even if chicken is healthy.

Comment: What's your dbms? mysql or postgresql?

Comment: You should _specify_ the expected result, not _describe_ it.

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: If the expected result is only vegetable then why is chicken marked as healthy?

Comment: @d0little Well chicken might be considered lean white meat, while burgers are red meat and more fatty.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If it is not considered healthy then why is it marked as healthy though...? Unfortunately it is impossible to code the nuance of nutrition into a SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL or Postgres, we can try aggregating:

```
SELECT type
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY type
HAVING SUM(nutrition <> 'healthy') = 0;
```